# How to remove unicode from the string in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode

```
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *descriptionText;

    NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:
    [htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] 
          options:@{ 
            NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType 
           } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

descriptionText.attributedText=attributedString;
```

The string is passed to the application through a JSON API. The above code eliminated the HTML tags and escape sequences but unicode still remains.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

-[NSString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]